# Specifying that a constrained generic class is a subclass?

Tags: c#

I have this class definition:

```
public abstract class AbstractListViewModel<T>  : AbstractWorkspaceViewModel
```

So I have a class called `AbstractListViewModel` that has a generic type, and that is a subclass of `AbstractWorkspaceViewModel`.

However, I need to constrain `T` to only be subclasses of `AbstractWorkspaceViewModel`. I tried the following:

```
public abstract class AbstractListViewModel<T> where T :
    AbstractWorkspaceViewModel, : AbstractWorkspaceViewModel
public abstract class AbstractListViewModel<T> where T :
    AbstractWorkspaceViewModel : AbstractWorkspaceViewModel
```

But this syntax is invalid.

So here I am trying to say "A class called `AbstractListViewModel` that is a subclass of `AbstractWorkspaceViewModel` and has a generic type that is also a subclass of `AbstractWorkspaceViewModel`.

How do I define this?

Comment: Your class names are incredibly confusing.

Comment: @asawyer I probably should have changed them for the question. They make sense in context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the ordering of your constraint. Try this:

```
public abstract class AbstractListViewModel<T>  : AbstractWorkspaceViewModel
    where T : AbstractWorkspaceViewModel
```

Answer (score 3):

You want this:

```
public abstract class AbstractListViewModel<T> : AbstractWorkspaceViewModel
    where T : AbstractWorkspaceViewModel
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class AbstractListViewModel<T> : AbstractWorkspaceViewModel where T : AbstractWorkspaceViewModel
```